# Meaning of arclength for projectile

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the arc length would represent for a projectile.

Say I had
$$f(t)=-t^2+5t$$

I can find the arc length of the curve above the x-axis
$$\int_0^5\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}dt\approx13.904$$
But what did I find in terms of the projectile?

The distance traveled would be given by
$$\int_0^5|f'(t)|dt=12.5$$
The displacement would be
$$\int_0^5f'(t)dt=0$$
The average height would be
$$\frac15\int_0^5f(t)dt\approx4.167$$
But what is this integral supposed to represent for the projectile?
$$\int_0^5\sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}dt\approx13.904$$

Comment: I assume $f(x)$ is the height of the projectile. What is $x$: the distance along the $x$-axis or time?

Comment: I guess it would be better to put it as $f(t)$ as it's supposed to be time.

Answer (score 2):

The arc length is the length of the trajectory curve 
$$
(t, f(t))
$$
from $(0, f(0))$ to $(5, f(5))$, thus the distance traveled.

It is derived from the differential arc element $ds$ with
$$
ds^2 = dt^2 + dy^2 = dt^2 + (\dot{f}(t))^2 dt^2 = (1 + (\dot{f}(t))^2) dt^2
$$

The next two interpretations ("distance", "displacement") are wrong.

Comment: Then do those two integrals have any significance?

Comment: The second is $f(5) - f(0)$, (displacement in $y$-direction).

Comment: The first is total (unsigned) area below $f'$ on $[0, 5]$.

Comment: The point is that these account only for the movement in $y$-direction, but the motion happens in both directions.